# Accessing Mutators in Vuex Store from Component yields Unknown Mutation Type Error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a `number` in my Vuex state. I am able to use `number` in my Vue component via a computed property successfully. In that Vue component, I have a method that activates a mutator in the Vuex store. This mutator then changes the value of `number` to a random number.

However, I am having troubles activating the mutator in the Vuex store. I receive an error when I try to activate the mutator:

`[vuex] unknown mutation type: changeNumber`

`changeNumber` is the mutator in the Vuex store that changes `number` to a random number.

The following is my code. I can access the store directly with `this.$store.state.number` from the Vue component, but cannot seem to activate the mutator `changeNumber` with `this.$store.commit('changeNumber')`. I double checked my syntax and read through multiple tutorials, and they all seemed to use `this.$store.commit('mutation')` successfully.

```
var store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
    number: -1
  },
  getters: {
    getNumber: function(state) {
      return state.number;
    }
  },
  mutators: {
    changeNumber: function(state) {
        state.number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  store: store,
  computed: {
    number: function() {
        return this.$store.getters.getNumber;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    generate: function() {
        this.$store.commit('changeNumber');
    }
  }
});
```

My HTML is the following:

```
<div v-cloak id="app">
  <button v-on:click="generate">Generate</button>
  <h3>{{ number }}</h3>
</div>
```

This code can be viewed in a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/EanKeen/co0dpexm/123/), if needed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `mutations`, not `mutators`

```
var store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    number: -1
  },
  getters: {
    getNumber: function(state) {
      return state.number;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    changeNumber: function(state) {
        state.number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    }
  }
});
```